# How to calculate left eigenvectors in C++?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvector

I regularly use C++ and the Eigen Tux module to calculate the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors of a matrix. I would now like to look to calculate the left eigenvectors as defined in this screenshot:
[image]

Usually, I would use the following code to conduct analysis of `Eigen::MatrixXd X`

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> X_eigen(X)
```

then access the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using `X_eigen.eigenvalues()` and `X_eigen.eigenvectors()`.

Does anyone know how to do this for left eigenvectors (i.e. row vectors)? Hope this explanation is clear enough and any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

I have been through the literature on the eigen Tux website but have not found anything of use to me yet.

Comment: Try transposing the equation.

Comment: This will not work as X is not generally a symmetric matrix, i.e. X^T not equal to X.

Comment: Sure, but either way the transpose satisfies the "right" eigenvalue equation. Then transpose the solutions again.